# Python code not working from cron job but works from command line via virtualenv

Tags: python, cron

I am receiving different errors which I cannot determine the issue. It seems as though it has to do with the configparser.py NoSectionError(section). This code runs fine from the command line in the virtualenv.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/configparser.py", line 1135, in _unify_values
    sectiondict = self._sections[section]
KeyError: 'token'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lvensel/projects/worklion01/worklion01/wl_cron.py", line 15, in <module>
    wl_post_projects.post()
  File "/home/lvensel/projects/worklion01/worklion01/wl_post_projects.py", line 15, in post
    import wl_get_background_jobs
  File "/home/lvensel/projects/worklion01/worklion01/wl_get_background_jobs.py", line 12, in <module>
    oauth, token = wl_secure_token.fetch_token()
  File "/home/lvensel/projects/worklion01/worklion01/wl_secure_token.py", line 17, in fetch_token
    values = wl_get_ini.get_values()
  File "/home/lvensel/projects/worklion01/worklion01/wl_get_ini.py", line 13, in get_values
    'token_url': config.get('token', 'token_url'),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/configparser.py", line 778, in get
    d = self._unify_values(section, vars)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/configparser.py", line 1138, in _unify_values
    raise NoSectionError(section)
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'token'
```

Comment: Stick to the question, please do not add irrelevant info. Edit is advised

Comment: We do not have an easy way to help you as it runs from _your_ VMWare box.

Comment: Is it okay for me to add a screenshot image with this post?

Comment: If it is the absolute last resort, you can post a screen shot. It would better to learn how to interact with your virtual machine more directly, though.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess on what potentially happens:

- `Cron` jobs are run by `root`
- virtualenv is run by your `user` with a custom python environment.
- `root` does not know about your virtualenv, then cannot match your user's python environment, thus your script fails. Probably with some `cannot import` or alike errors.

Have a look at replies [here](https://superuser.com/questions/871704/why-does-root-cron-job-script-need-sudo-to-run-properly).

Comment: I added the errors in my original post above. @m-ric I solved the issue that you described above by utilizing this in cron: /srv/.virtualenvs/worklion/bin/python.  At least I think that solved it or or is just making it further down the code and failing because of the same issue that you are describing?